# Should the adverb 'either' go before or after the verb in this sentence?

Tags: adverb-placement, either-any

My friends.

I wonder.

> 1. You can **either** pay by cash or use a credit card.
> 2. You can pay **either** by cash or use a credit card.

Which one is true? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "either", the two options that follow should be able to form complete sentences with whatever appears *before* the word. In your example, you have *two different verbs* - "pay" and "use". For this reason, I think "*either*" needs to go *before* the verb "pay":

> You can either pay by cash or use a credit card.

This is the same as writing:

> You can:
>   1. pay by cash
>   2. use a credit card

The two options are, therefore:

> 1. You can pay by cash.
> 2. You can use a credit card.

If you use the verb "pay" *before* you declare the options, it would be like giving the options:

> 1. You can pay by cash.
> 2. You can pay use a credit card. <- *this makes no sense*

Comment: Worth noting that (for the reasons above) "You can pay either by cash or credit card." also works!